# Next.js: Run methods on server startup

Tags: next.js

I am looking for a way to run some configuration methods when my Next.js server first boots. For example to initialize some variables and a connection to a database.
For now, I am checking whether the variables have been initialized yet whenever I need them in an endpoint handler, but this does not seem like the ideal way of doing things.

Is there any way to better handle this?

Comment: Your question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78146566/8003058).

Answer (score 1):

#### Storing variables

1. The simplest, yet most performant way of storing variables are build-time variables, which are declared in all the `.env` files. They're pretty basic, can't store objects and there's not much you can do if you want them to be dynamically declared. Docs: [Environment Variables](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables)
2. If you want to have more control over how your variables are constructed, you might use run-time variables, which are declared in the `next.config.js` file. One benefit is that you are allowed to store objects, or construct your variables using functions. Similarly to the option above, you may decide whether you want the variables to be available on the client-side or the server-side - just remember that you'll lose static site generation if you need run-time client-side variables. Also, be aware that this file is not run through any compiler like Babel, so stick to plain old JS supported by your version of Node. Docs: [Runtime configuration](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/runtime-configuration)
3. If both of the above do not fit your needs, I'd suggest considering writing custom Node/Bash scripts executed from the `package.json` file in order to set system env variables or to generate your `.env` or `.next.config.js` files.

#### Caching database connection

If you want to cache database connection the solution may depend on your database driver/provider. For example, the MongoDB driver offers a build-in caching system that requires only a little configuration in your app. I'd suggest looking for either Next.js or Node-specific documentation in your DB provider's docs. Here's the aforementioned article regarding Mongo: [How to Integrate MongoDB Into Your Next.js App](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/how-to/nextjs-with-mongodb/)