# Is there a run once server-side startup method in next?

Tags: next.js

I want to change the default parsing of numeric types returned by node-postgres, as explained [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-types). I want to make this change once for the whole application. Here's the code from the docs...

```
var types = require('pg').types
types.setTypeParser(20, function(val) {
  return parseInt(val, 10)
})
```

My question is where do I put this code? Is there a run-once server-side startup method in next? My question seems to be asked but not answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68600756/next-js-run-methods-on-server-startup).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [instrumentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/instrumentation) file convention. This file exports a `register` function that will be called upon server startup. Please note that **this feature is experimental**.

```js
import { types } from "pg";
 
export function register() {
  types.setTypeParser(20, (val) => parseInt(val, 10));
}
```

Just add the file in the root directory of your project (or inside the src folder if using one). To use it, you must explicitly opt in by defining `instrumentationHook` in your `next.config.js`:

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  experimental: { instrumentationHook: true },
};
```